# Handling complexity in JavaFX application architecture (applicable to almost any stateful application)

Tags: java, architecture, javafx-8

To better understand my question I will give my requirement. This JavaFX application needs to create, edit and export a very big form that has many rules for its completion and the user requires a lot of guiding. Furthermore these rules and even the form structure changes significantly every 1 month or even less.Another problem is that the rules are somewhat complicated, there's very few components that can be correctly completed without knowing the form state in a completely different part of it.

So I'm looking for a way to code things that makes it very easily maintainable.

What I have tried until now:

Created a massive tree-like data structure that resembles the GUI tree and stored the form state in it. Used this structure to contain most of the logic through bindings inside of it. The GUI binds to it.

Problems encountered:

- I have to write a lot of change listeners because I cannot double bind to an Object property of an Object property easily.
- UI logic leaks into custom cells of lists into the bindings. Example:

  ```
  view.getDenumire().textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
      if (newValue != null && getItem().getTip()!= SerieFacturiModel.TipSerieFacturi.SIMPLU){
          getItem().setDenumire(newValue);
      }
  });
  ```

  I had to write about a hundred or more of these and many times they have some logic in them or trigger some other GUI changes (errors, do their own validation, sometimes the validation is dependent on the big form state -- application state)

So I'm really looking for a way to code where validation rules, syncing with the model, GUI interaction with application state are separate things, very easy to write and do not require more than 2 changes if an update is needed(one that contains the logic, one that enables injection if it wasn't part of an API beforehand).

Bonus question: Assume an event creates 2 event chains (where the processing of an event creates another event, etc.) that depend on and alter one stateful resource, is there a way to have any idea what the end result is? How do you make it so that the application can never be in an incorrect state?

Comment: hey have you found  a solution to this that you can share ?

Comment: turns out that showing and manipulating data are inherently tightly coupled. There is an option to create the view based on your model, but then you need to include declarative info about how the view should look or be validated, etc. This gives you less or more complicated configurability of your view but makes it easier and faster to write forms. Try and take a look at ControlsFX validation, formsfx, preferencesFX. Otherwise you are pretty much stuck at managing your bindings manually and writing custom code for each validation.